# Try catch block with an if statement

Tags: java, try-catch

So I got some problems implementing a try catch block in my program. It's quite simple, all I want is to throw an exception whenever the user enters a 0 or less into my dialog window. Here is my code:

```
try {
    if (this.sides <= 0);
} catch (NegativeSidesException exception) {
    System.out.println(exception + "You entered 0 or less");
}
```

The `NegativeSidesException` is my own defined exception.

When I make 0 the input the try catch block doesn't catch it and the compiler throws a normal exception and terminates the program.

Comment: You are missing a throw statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change 
    `if (this.sides <= 0);`

To
   `if (this.sides <= 0) throw new Exception ("some error message");`

And every thing will work as you want

Answer (score 9):

Create a new object for the exception and throw it explicitly.

```
try{
    if (this.sides <= 0)
        throw new NegativeSidesException();
}
catch (NegativeSidesException exception)
{
    System.out.println(exception + "You entered 0 or less");        
}
```

Comment: This solved it thanks! Do I always have to create a new object for the exception, or is it just when I have my own defined?

Comment: When you want to create an exception by yourself(explicitly) doesn't matter its a custom or java default exception then you need to create a new object and use `throw` keyword so that following catch can control the flow of execution from there.

Answer (score 8):

You have so bad syntax :)

1. `if` statement as it is doesn't throw exception of it's own

Lets repeat :)

**If:**

```
if(condition){
 //commands while true
}

if(condition)
 //if there is just 1 command, you dont need brackets

if(condition){
 //cmd if true
}else{
 //cmd for false
}

 //theoretically (without brackets in case of single command following)
    if(condition)
     //true command;
    else
     //false command;
```

**Try-Catch:**

```
try{
 //danger code
}catch(ExceptionClass e){
 //work with exception 'e'
}
```

2. There are more ways how to show the custom message:

```
    try{
        if (this.sides <= 0){
              throw new NegativeSidesException();
        }else{
               //make code which you want- entered value is above zero
               //in fact, you dont need else there- once exception is thrown, it goes into catch automatically
        }
    }catch(NegativeSidesException  e){
       System.out.println(e + "You entered 0 or less");
    }
```

Or maybe better (you will do not loose information about exception thrown):

```
    try{
        if (this.sides > 0){
             //do what you want
        }else{
               throw new NegativeSidesException();
        }
     }catch(NegativeSidesException  e){
        System.out.println(e + "You entered 0 or less");
     }
```

Btw You can use java default [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) (that message is better to specify as constant in above of class):

```
throw new Exception("You entered 0 or less"); 
//in catch block
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```